# How to write text in the middle of a file in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, text-files

I would like to know how to write text in a middle of a file in vbscript.
The text file has 2 lines, one line for the name of the output and the second of the value. The outputs separated by ";"
For example : 
Before insert text, the text file contain -

> mem1;mem2;mem3;
>   0.15;15.5;12.3;

After insert new text -

> mem1;mem2;mem3;mem4
>   0.15;15.5;12.3;13.2

Thanks of helping me!

P.S. - note that it should be txt file and not csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this snippet:

```
'Usage: 
'If ReplaceInFile(filename, search, replace, addToEnd) = 0 Then 
'   WScript.Echo "Succeeded"
'End If

Function ReplaceInFile(strFilename, strSearch, strReplace, addToEnd)
    Dim fso, objFile, oldContent, newContent

    'Does file exist?
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(strFilename) = False Then
       ReplaceInFile = 0
       Exit Function
    End If

    'Read file
    Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilename, 1)
    oldContent = objFile.ReadAll

    'Write file
    newContent = replace(oldContent, strSearch, strReplace, 1, 1, 0)
    newContent = newContent & addToEnd 
    Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilename, 2)
    objFile.Write newContent
    objFile.Close 
    ReplaceInFile = 0
End Function
```

So you can use like this:

```
If ReplaceInFile("your file path", ";\r\n", "mem4", "13.2") = 0 Then 
   WScript.Echo "Succeeded"
End If
```

**WARNING!!**
**This assumes that the last line does not have a new line at the end!**

Comment: Really should consider when packaging up functions, declaring local variables using `Dim` so they remain in the local scope. As it stands, variables like `fso` could be manipulated outside of the functions local scope and give weird results or outright break the function. This is why it is also important to have `Option Explicit` to avoid undeclared variables becoming a problem.